# LINQ to Datatable Group by and return all columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable

```
ID  Age Last name   First Name  Sex class   Father_Name Mother_Name Marks
1   20  A   B   M   1   A   B   50
1   20  A   B   M   1   A   B   50
1   20  A   B   M   1   A   B   100
2   15  F   G   F   2   H   J   40
2   15  F   G   F   2   H   J   50
```

& I want following results after applying Linq Group by

```
1   20  A   B   M   1   A   B   200
2   15  F   G   F   2   H   J   90
```

I am able to get the sum but i am not able to get the other columns in LINQ group by

Can anyone help on this

```
var drResults = from r1 in dtResults.AsEnumerable()
                            group r1 by new 
                                {
                                   MarksSum=  r1.Field<int>("Marks"),

                                }
                                into g
                            select new
                            {


                                    Total = g.Sum(r1=>r1.Field<int>("Marks"))                                   
                            };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var _result =   from r1 in dtResults.AsEnumerable()
                group r1 by new
                {
                    ID = r1.Field<int>("ID"),
                    Age = r1.Field<int>("Age"),
                    LastName =  r1.Field<int>("LastName"),
                    FirstName = r1.Field<int>("FirstName"),
                    Sex =  r1.Field<int>("Sex"),
                    Class =  r1.Field<int>("class"),
                    Father_Name =  r1.Field<int>("Father_Name"),
                    Mother_Name =  r1.Field<int>("Mother_Name")
                } into g
                select new
                {
                    ID = g.Key.ID,
                    Age = g.Key.Age,
                    LastName =  g.Key.LastName,
                    FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                    Sex =  g.Key.Sex,
                    Class =  g.Key.Class,
                    Father_Name =  g.Key.Father_Name,
                    Mother_Name =  g.Key.Mother_Name,
                    TotalMark = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Marks"))
                };
```

Comment: I have added a version of your answer with lambda syntax for completeness!  I also added an upper C to "class" which will not compile.

Comment: How could we do this with the method syntax ?

Comment: Can this be done without listing EVERY SINGLE column name twice? What about a DataTable with let's say 100 columns and we want to group-by using just one of the columns and display the rest?

Answer (score 4):

You want to group by the `Id`?! Then you can use `Sum` the `Marks` on the group:

```
var result = from r in dtResults.AsEnumerable()
             group r by r.Field<int>("ID") into IdGroup
             let row = IdGroup.First()
             select new
             {
                 ID = IdGroup.Key,
                 Age = row.Field<int>("Age"),
                 LastName = row.Field<string>("Last_Name"),
                 FirstName = row.Field<string>("First_Name"),
                 MotherName = row.Field<string>("Mother_Name"),
                 FatherName = row.Field<string>("Father_Name"),
                 Marks = IdGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Marks"))
             };
```

**Update**

> Hey Tim, if all rows have different values then what should i do? e.g
>   LastName is different and ID is same. I have some data which is
>   corrupt or you can say redundant in that case i am asking.

It's out of the scope of this question to show how you can "repair" your `DataTable`. But if you instead want to list all rows even when they have the same ID, but witht he correct summed `Mark` per Id-Group, you can use this query:

```
var result = from r in dtResults.AsEnumerable()
             group r by r.Field<int>("ID") into IdGroup
             let IdTotalMarks = IdGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Marks"))
             from row in IdGroup
             select new
             {
                 ID = IdGroup.Key,
                 Age = row.Field<int>("Age"),
                 LastName = row.Field<string>("Last Name"),
                 FirstName = row.Field<string>("First Name"),
                 MotherName = row.Field<string>("Mother Name"),
                 FatherName = row.Field<string>("Father_Name"),
                 Marks = IdTotalMarks
             };
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch about grouping by Id only. I suggest you to introduce new range variable for first group item `let first = IdGroup.First()`

Comment: What this First() method does?

Comment: @vicky selects first row from group. Thus all other rows have same values for columns (except last column), you don't need to get values from each row of tables

Comment: Hey Tim, if all rows have different values then what should i do? e.g LastName is different and ID is same

Comment: @vicky: I assume that they are related(Id is the UserID and LastName is the user's LastName), so why is that possible?

Comment: I have some data which is corrupt or you can say redundant in that case i am asking

Comment: So which name do you want to take in these cases since it's not clear? However, repairing your DataTable is a different (interesting) question in my opinion. You could aks another question.

Comment: @vicky: I have edited my answer to provide a different approach to list all your rows (but with the summed marks per ID).

Answer (score 1):

JW's answer with Lambda syntax (I have also renamed the field "class" as this won't compile):

```
       var _result = dtResults
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r1 => new
            {
                ID = r1.Field<int>("ID"),
                Age = r1.Field<int>("Age"),
                LastName =  r1.Field<string>("LastName"),
                FirstName = r1.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                Sex =  r1.Field<int>("Sex"),
                Class =  r1.Field<int>("class"),
                Father_Name =  r1.Field<string>("Father_Name"),
                Mother_Name =  r1.Field<string>("Mother_Name")
            }).Select(g => new
            {
                ID = g.Key.ID,
                Age = g.Key.Age,
                LastName =  g.Key.LastName,
                FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                Sex =  g.Key.Sex,
                Class =  g.Key.Class,
                Father_Name =  g.Key.Father_Name,
                Mother_Name =  g.Key.Mother_Name,
                TotalMark = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Marks"))
            });
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but some of the int's in your query should be strings.  Example: LastName =  r1.Field<int>("LastName") should be LastName =  r1.Field<string>("LastName")