# LINQ to DataSet DataTable Group By - Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I have a Dataset that contains e.g. id, date, other fields...

[image]

I want to retrieve unique rows based on ids and latest date.

I have this query but I can't figure out where to put the date condition.

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("id"))
                     .Select(group => group.First())
                     .CopyToDataTable();

r.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();

gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();
```

The result should be

```
1 - 8/2/2014
2 - 1/8/2014
4 - 1/2/2011
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `OrderByDescending` for `Date` Field and then select First:

```
 .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(r=> r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).First())
```

So your query would be:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("id"))
                .Select(group => group
                                .OrderByDescending(r=> r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                                .First())
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this: [LINQ to Datatable Group by and return all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448222/linq-to-datatable-group-by-and-return-all-columns)

And only return the field that you want, p.e. date